# How can I get the controlling field API name if I have the picklist API name

Tags: apex

I have different dependent pick lists. Example Pick list-1 If I select country _India then in states pick-list-2 filed there must be only Indian states.After selecting the State_Karnataka the pick-list-3 must be only for Cities in Karnataka.

I am using Lightning so for my java-script code I just need to pass controlling Field API name.

How can I access the Controlling field API name through Apex code ?

I know it can be done through Tooling API but not sure how.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the `getController()` method on the [`DescribeFieldResult Class`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm).

```
SObjectField controllingPicklist = MyObject__c.MyPicklist__c.getDescribe().getController();
```

Comment: How can I pass the pick list name as a string ? As I want to pass the pick list field name and Object name Dynamically.

Thanks for giving me above solution.

Comment: @NupurBhagat Replace `MyObject__c.MyPicklist__c` in Adrian's code with `MyObject__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('MyPickList__c')`.